# adding actions to button, error code

Tags: codenameone

I'm working on an app project on codenameone and I want to add an action so that every time a user types some text, into a text area on a screen of the app, it gets added to a box (Json). So I select the text area on the screen, I click on "events" and select "action events". Usually nothing should appear at this point, but I get a window asking to give a name and save a file.

Since I inserted the name and save to close the window, when I repeat all the process and select "Action Events" an error message is shown:

"Error opening Netbeans (...) Cannot running program (...)* : Create process error=2, Specified file not found".

*the name which follows is the one I created when the window appeared to me.

I also created the project again and I'm having the same problem here: by going to "Events" and clicking on "Action Events" I got the same error:

"Error opening Netbeans (...) Cannot running program (...)* : Create process error=2, Specified file not found".

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you running and how are you creating your projects (Steps)?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1 on windows 7 x64

Comment: Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: yes, now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Kindly upvote and mark as answer if it does fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup Netbeans, Open your theme.res by double clicking.

Choose **Codename One** -> **Advance** -> **Reset Netbeans Settings**. Then,

Choose **file** -> **setup Netbeans** and navigate to where your Netbeans.exe is, On my PC I did the this:

This PC -> Program Files -> Netbeans 8.1 -> bin -> netbeans.exe (or netbeans64.exe).

Your steps may be similar, depending on your computer.

Save theme.res and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply, it does work now!

Comment: Kindly upvote and mark as answer if it does fix the problem

Comment: @robetalrp You have a checkbox next to the answer that is grayed out. Click it to mark the answer as answered